# Can a Greasemonkey script read Firefox history database?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

Can a Greasemonkey script read Firefox history database?
If no, why? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Firefox stores its history in [the *Places*, SQLite database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places).  Two ways to access that would be to access the `places.sqlite` file or to use [the Storage, database API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage).  **Both methods are specifically forbidden to ordinary JavaScript** because bad people can (and have) used such capabilities to commit crimes.

While, Greasemonkey theoretically *could* allow GM scripts to do these things, [GM's developers have chosen not to](http://wiki.greasespot.net/FAQ#Can_Greasemonkey_be_used_to_open_local_files.3F).  So, essentially you can't access the history because untrusted javascript can't do that and the developers of Greasemonkey will not unlock any but one or two of the capabilities of "privileged" javascript. They are trying to protect casual users of GM who might unknowingly install a malicious script.

So Greasemonkey does not have this ability and likely never will. But, you can [write your own extension](http://crossrider.com/) to get the ability to see the history.